# How to replace last \*\.. in string use RE in Python

Tags: python, regex

i need do parse path and get the parent dir .

str = '.\Workspace\1st Project\ww.settings..'
tostr  = '.\Workspace\1st Project'

i try some 
        bb = re.compile(r".*\w+.*\s*\w*\s*\w+\..$")
        tostr re.sub(bb, "",str)

but not good for all special path have some ".", " " characket in the path.  such as: "ww.settings",  "VC6.0green" , ".setting" , "sublime text. setting" ,etc

how to make a good RE match it, and i can replace it and get the correct parent dir.

Comment: what's your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer with a regex (no wonder why)

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iA1yO5/1)

The regex should be `^(.+)\\.*$`

It capture all before the last `\`

Comment: <pre>\\[^\\]+\\\.{2}$ <code>
i use this ,so far can sub the words from the last second \ .

Comment: Seems I got it, the tittle is more correct than the question text. And @avinash-raj was right while editing in this case. So `^(.+)\\.+\\.*$` would be better [Regex updated here](http://regex101.com/r/iA1yO5/4)

Answer (score 1):

No need to reinvent the wheel :) Use [os.path module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html). There are very useful functions for your task, such as os.path.normpath

Answer (score 0):

To extract the path components:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'[^\\]+')
test_str = u".\Workspace\1st Project\ww.settings\.."
re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex which uses positive lookahead,

```
>>> s = ".\eric4-4.5.21\.VC6.0green"
>>> m = re.sub(r'^(.*)(?=\\[^.]*\.).*',r'\1', s)
>>> m
'.\\eric4-4.5.21'
```